# SortedIntSet: a set of integers that can be iterated in ascending order in O(N) time

Tags: python, integer, bitwise, set

I needed a set with the following properties:

- can be iterated in ascending or descending order in \$O(N)\$ time
- the usual set operations (contains, add, remove, discard) can still be done in \$O(1)\$
- if it helps achieve the above, then the set can be constrained to integers within a preset range [minInt, maxInt]

Below is what I came up with (`IntSet` and `SortedIntSet`).

Any suggestions are welcome.

#### Constructor

One thing in particular I would like feedback on is on the `IntSet` constructor. I made the constructor so that it can take 0, 1, or 2 integer arguments followed by 0 or 1 iterables. The particular way in which I did this seems messy, so if you know of a better way, let me know please and thank you! It would be great if the constructor could take keyword arguments (for `minInt`, `maxInt`, and `iterable`) as well. For completeness here's a table that summarizes the current behavior of the constructor with different number/types of input:

|  | `IntSet( )` | `IntSet( 63)` | `IntSet( 5, 13)` | `IntSet( [3, 5, 7])` | `IntSet( 63, [3, 5, 7])` | `IntSet( 5, 13, [3, 5, 7])` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `self.minInt =` | `DEF_MIN_INT` | `DEF_MIN_INT` | `5` | `DEF_MIN_INT` | `DEF_MIN_INT` | `5` |
| `self.maxInt =` | `DEF_MAX_INT` | `63` | `13` | `DEF_MAX_INT` | `63` | `13` |
| `iterable =` | `()` | `()` | `()` | `[3, 5, 7]` | `[3, 5, 7]` | `[3, 5, 7]` |

#### Implementation

```
class IntSet(set):
    DEF_MIN_INT = 0
    DEF_MAX_INT = 31
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        '''
        A set whose elements are integers in the range [minInt, maxInt].
        
        This set can be iterated in ascending order in O(C) time where C = maxInt - minInt + 1.
        If you will iterate through this set often, then it is recommended you use a SortedIntSet instead which can be iterated in ascedning order in O(N) time where N = len(self) <= C.
        
        The set is implemented as a single number of C-bits where C = maxInt - minInt + 1.
        '''
        
        type_error_msg = f'IntSet expected at most 2 integer arguments followed by at most 1 iterable argument, but got {args}'
        
        # order matters
        iterable = ()
        if args and not isinstance(args[-1], int):
            iterable = args.pop()
        self.maxInt = type(self).DEF_MAX_INT
        if args:
            if not isinstance(args[-1], int):
                raise TypeError(type_error_msg)
            self.maxInt = args.pop()
        self.minInt = type(self).DEF_MIN_INT
        if args:
            if not isinstance(args[-1], int):
                raise TypeError(type_error_msg)
            self.minInt = args.pop()
        if args:
            raise TypeError(type_error_msg)
        
        self.num = 0
        self.__len = 0
        for val in iterable:
            self.add(val)
    
    def validate(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, int):
            raise TypeError('elements must be integers')
        if not self.minInt <= val <= self.maxInt:
            raise ValueError('element values must be within [{minInt}, {maxInt}]')
    
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.num != 0
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len
    
    def __contains__(self, val):
        # to validate or not validate?
        return self.num & 1 << (val - self.minInt)

    def add(self, val, pow2Val=None): # pow2Val is a one-hot (power of 2) number so it can't be 0
        if not pow2Val:
            self.validate(val)
            pow2Val = 1 << (val - self.minInt)
        if self.num & pow2Val:
            return False
        self.num |= pow2Val
        self.__len += 1
        return True

    def remove(self, val):
        if not self.discard(val):
            raise KeyError(val)
    
    def discard(self, val):
        self.validate(val)
        pow2Val = 1 << (val - self.minInt)
        if not self.num & pow2Val:
            return False
        self.num &= ~pow2Val
        self.__len -= 1
        return True

    def __iter__(self):
        num = self.num
        val = self.minInt
        while num:
            if num & 0b1:
                yield val
            num >>= 1
            val += 1


class SortedIntSet(IntSet):
    '''
    An IntSet that can be iterated in ascending order in O(N) time where N == len(self)
    '''
    @classmethod
    def fromIntSet(cls, intSet):
        return cls(intSet.minInt, intSet.maxInt, iter(intSet))
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
        # for each value val in the set, self.log2[2 ** (val - self.minInt)] == val
        self.log2 = {} # to find the position of the 1 bit in a one-hot (power of 2) number in O(1)
    
    def add(self, val):
        self.validate(val)
        pow2Val = 1 << (val - self.minInt)
        if super().add(val, pow2Val):
            self.log2[pow2Val] = val
    
    def __iter__(self):
        num = self.num
        while num:
            yield self.log2[num & -num] # num & -num isolates the rightmost 1
            num &= num - 1 # clears the rightmost 1
```

And here's a "improved" version of `SortedSetInt` in which all `SortedSetInt` instances share a single `LOG2` `dict`:

```
class IntSet:
    # the same implementation of IntSet as above, with one modification:
    def add(self, val):
        self.validate(val)
        pow2Val = 1 << (val - self.minInt)
        if self.num & pow2Val:
            return False
        self.num |= pow2Val
        self.__len += 1
        return True


class SortedIntSet(IntSet):
    '''
    An IntSet that can be iterated in ascending order in O(N) time where N == len(self)
    '''
    LOG2 = {}
    pow2Val = 1 << type(self).DEF_MIN_INT
    for val in range(type(self)).DEF_MIN_INT, type(self).DEF_MAX_INT):
        LOG2[pow2Val] = val
        pow2Val <<= 1
    
    @classmethod
    def fromIntSet(cls, intSet):
        return cls(intSet.minInt, intSet.maxInt, iter(intSet))
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
    
    def add(self, val):
        if super().add(val):
            type(self).LOG2[1 << val] = val
    
    def __iter__(self):
        num = self.num
        while num:
            yield type(self).LOG2[num & -num] + self.minInt # num & -num isolates the rightmost 1
            num &= num - 1
```

Comment: @FMc The min/max bounds are not actual requirements. I imagine most applications will be fine with a `minInt` of `0` and having a `maxInt` is nice to ensure python's (arbitrary-precision) ints don't get too big, but it's also not a requirement. I can provide an implementation version that does away with min/max if it helps!

Answer (score 3):

I am a year late reviewing this, but what the heck. I overall like your `SortedIntSet` (I will have a few suggestions as to how it might be improved). To paraphrase Mark Twain who apologized to friend for not having the time to have written to him a shorter, more concise letter, if I had a bit more time my response would have been edited down with repetitive verbiage removed. For that I apologize in advance.

**The Code as Posted Will Not Run**

In `IntSet.__init__` you have the call `args.pop()`. But `args` is a `tuple`, which has no `pop` method. You would need to first execute `args = list(args)` before you could do a `pop` call. Second, this method calls method `add` for each element of the *iterable* argument. But in method `SortedIntSet.__init__` you are setting `self.log2 = {}` *after* the base *constructor* is invoked and that is too late; there will be no attribute `log2` when the overridden `add` method is called.

**`IntSet` Discussion**

First, one small point: You stated that you need a set that "can be iterated in ascending or descending order in O(N)." It is generally understood that `N` would represents the number of elements in the set. Although iterating a `SortedIntSet` appears to be O(N), that is not the case for the `IntSet`, which depends on what range of values can be stored and what values are stored. For example, if you have an instance of the set where the minimum value can be 0 and the maximum value can be 2_000_000_000 and you add a single integer value 2_000_000_000 to the set, then the `__iter__` method will need to execute its `while num` loop 2_000_000_000 times just to yield the one and only integer in the set.

Second, I have an issue with your use of inheritance. You have chosen to inherit `IntSet` from `set`. In object-oriented programming, inheritance is a technique for both code reuse and interface reuse. Interface reuse is more of an issue with strongly-typed languages such as C++ and Java where you must define function arguments and variables with their specific types. But note that there are other ways of implementing code reuse that do not rely on inheritance. For example, your `IntSet` could have an attribute that is `set` instance and methods such as `add` can ultimately delegate to that `set` instance attribute. This would have been a better approach in my opinion for the following reason:

It's true that inheritance is often used in Python just for code reuse. But you not only inherit `IntSet` from `set` but also imply that it is a type of set. The problem is that an `IntSet` is *not* a `set` in the IS-A sense, i.e. `IntSet` is not a *subtype* of `set` behaviorally (see [Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)). The question becomes "can you substitute an instance of `IntSet` for an instance of `set`?" and the answer is no. First, even though an `int` IS-A `object`, a set of `int` elements does not have a `IS-A` relationship with a `set` of `object` elements. To the latter I should be able to add an arbitrary `object`. But if I try to add anything other than an `int` to the `IntSet` instance, an exception is raised. So an `IntSet` instance cannot be used wherever a `set` instance is expected. Furthermore, you have not overridden enough `set` methods to make `IntSet` work correctly. For example, if I call `pop` an exception will be raised because the `set.pop` implementation will not see any elements in the set. Also, calling a method like `union` will not achieve the desired results.

**If you had described this class as being a *container* that holds `int` elements and supports certain methods and that inheritance was only being used for implementation, I would have had little issue with the class.** The only issue I would still have is that a cleaner implementation would be to (implicitly) inherit from `object` and instead delegate method calls to a private `set` attribute. Also, if you needed a standalone set-like container to hold integers, you would only need to ensure that the argument to the `add` method (which would delegate to its internal set's `add` method) was an integer. That implementation, of course, would make it unsuitable as a base class for `SortedIntSet`. But we shall see that `SortedIntSet` does not need to inherit from anything other than `object`.

**`SortedIntSet` Discussion**

Because I find`IntSet` not particularly useful as a standalone class because its current implementation is not particularly efficient for that purpose and your true end goal anyway is to implement a `SortedIntSet` class, I would:

1. Discard `IntSet` altogether as a base class and instead have your sorted integer "set" inherit from `object`. I would, of course, salvage code from your now discarded `IntSet` class to be used for the sorted version.
2. Use the name `Set` in the class name if you really must but then make it clear that it only supports a subset of `set` operations. I would prefer a class name of `SortedIntContainer`, a more descriptive name.

The following code also demonstrates one way of handling arguments being passed to the constructor. Also note that I am naming "private" attributes and methods with a leading underscore:

```py
class SortedIntContainer:
    '''
    A container that can be iterated in ascending order in O(N) time where N == len(self)
    '''

    DEF_MIN_INT = 0
    DEF_MAX_INT = 31

    def __init__(self, min_int=None, max_int=None, iterable=None):
        if min_int is None:
            min_int = self.DEF_MIN_INT
        elif not isinstance(min_int, int):
            raise TypeError('Argument min_int is not an int.')

        if max_int is None:
            max_int = self.DEF_MAX_INT
        elif not isinstance(max_int, int):
            raise TypeError('Argument max_int is not an int.')

        if max_int < min_int:
            raise TypeError('Argument max_int is less than argument min_int.')

        if iterable is None:
            iterable = ()
        elif not hasattr(iterable, '__iter__'):
            raise TypeError('Argument iterable cannot be iterated.')

        self._min_int = min_int
        self._max_int = max_int

        self._log2 = {} # to find the position of the 1 bit in a one-hot (power of 2) number in O(1) #Booboo
        self._num = 0
        self._len = 0
        for val in iterable:
            self.add(val)
        # for each value val in the set, self.log2[2 ** (val - self._min_int)] == val

    def _validate(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, int):
            raise TypeError('elements must be integers')
        if not self._min_int <= val <= self._max_int:
            raise ValueError('element values must be within [{min_int}, {max_int}]')

    def __bool__(self):
        return self._num != 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

    def __contains__(self, val):
        self._validate(val)
        return self._num & 1 << (val - self._min_int)

    def add(self, val):
        self._validate(val)

        pow2Val = 1 << (val - self._min_int)
        if self._num & pow2Val:
            return
        self._num |= pow2Val
        self._len += 1
        self._log2[pow2Val] = val

    def remove(self, val):
        if not self.discard(val):
            raise KeyError(val)

    def discard(self, val):
        self._validate(val)
        pow2Val = 1 << (val - self._min_int)
        if not self._num & pow2Val:
            return False
        self._num &= ~pow2Val
        self._len -= 1
        # Not strictly necessary, but perhaps useful:
        del self._log2[pow2Val]
        return True

    def __iter__(self):
        num = self._num
        while num:
            yield self._log2[num & -num] # num & -num isolates the rightmost 1
            num &= num - 1 # clears the rightmost 1

s = SortedIntContainer(1, 5, [3,2,1])
s.remove(2)
for n in s:
    print(n)
```

Prints:

```None
1
3
```

Note that method `__contains__` should validate its argument so that if, for example, a `float` were passed in a more meaningful exception would be raised.